# Ember-data bootstrapping model objects

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When bootstrapping Ember-data model objects with existing JSON that is not from a remote AJAX call, do I have to make the following 2 calls:

```
App.store.load(App.Account, data);
var account = App.store.find(App.Account, data.id);
```

Is it not possible to create the Object in one step, similar to calling `setProperties` on an existing Ember object?

Also, how would this work for creating a collection of Ember model objects?  For example:

```
var users = App.get('users');
App.store.loadMany(App.User, users);
this.set('content', App.store.findMany(App.User, users.mapProperty('id').uniq()));
```

The above seems wrong. How can I create these objects from existing JSON objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems ok to me, as `store.load*` returns something else than model objects (loaded `ids` & `clientIds`).

So far, I think there is no alternative.