# Bootstrapping data models in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would like to bootstrap an application with data without having to do an additional request. Assuming I have a simple user model with the following json:

```
{"user":{"id":1,"email":"test@example.com"}}
```

This json is being dumped by a Rails app. How best should I bootstrap my `User` model in Ember?

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
App.Store.load(App.YourModel, yourdata);
```

See this question:

[Ember-data bootstrapping model objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887944/ember-data-bootstrapping-model-objects)

edit: not sure if you can load multiple objects at once - you may have to loop your collection. Suggest using something like underscore.js

Comment: Use store.loadMany to load multiple objects at once. For example, store.loadMany(App.User, users);

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to bootstrap a Model from JSON then you should use the push() method as detailed here: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/#toc_pushing-records